# Seasonal Adjustment in R or Python

Tags: python, r, time-series

Does anybody know of a routine to do seasonal adjustment in Python or even better, in R? Here is an example data-set (South African CPI), which tends to have spikes in the first few months of the year:

[image: SA m/m CPI]

I would like to find the underlying pressures stripping out the seasonal factors, but I'd ideally like to use something fairly straightforward, built into either language, rather than interfacing or using outright an external package such as Demetra.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Step 1. Define the data.

(Obtained from http://www.statssa.gov.za/publications/P0141/P0141February2011.pdf)

```
CPI <- c(102.3, 103.1, 104.3, 105.7, 106.2, 106.6, 107, 108.2, 108.5, 108.9, 
        108.9, 108.9, 109.2, 109.5, 110.2, 111.1, 111.3, 111.5, 111.5, 
        112.2, 112.3, 112.4, 112.6, 112.8, 113, 113.5, 114.3)
```

Step 2. Calculate monthly change in index, and convert to time series object.

```
dCPI <- ts(CPI[-1] - CPI[-length(CPI)], start=2008, frequency=12)
```

Step 3. Use the function `stl()` to calculate seasonal, trend and residuals:

```
plot(stl(dCPI, "periodic"))
```

[image]

Comment: Step 4. Then subtract the seasonal component from the data to get seasonally adjusted data.

Comment: What does the "periodic" parameter mean, please Andrie? Also please note that the calculation for dCPI should be:
dCPI <- ts((CPI[-1] / CPI[-length(CPI)] - 1), .....

Comment: "periodic" is passed to parameter `s.window`.  See `?stl` for details.

Comment: @ Andrie, One more question: does the stl function do any exponential or other weighting to increase the influence of more recent data? I have checked ?stl and doesn't seem to.

Answer (score 0):

http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/scipy-user/2010-January/023847.html